# Problems with accessing files

Tags: php

Hello stackoverflow community, how can i solve this problem, here it is my error:

> **Warning**:  require_once(DP_BASE_DIR/classes/query.class.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file  or directory in

the that query.class.php is in the folder:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/classes/query.class.php
```

Im trying to access it from:
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/modules/tasks/ajax/file.php` here.
When i try to use:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/query.class.php'):
```

It works like a charm. But i need to acces that file using DP_BASE_DIR. So when i write:

```
require_once DP_BASE_DIR."/classes/query.class.php";
```

I get an error. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: what does `DP_BASE_DIR` resolve to?

Comment: where is `DP_BASE_DIR` defined? It could be a simple scope issue

Comment: @RamRaider @Macro Man in that query.class.php file there is if - `if (!(defined('DP_BASE_DIR'))) {
 die('This file should not be called directly.');
}` and thats why i cant access it without that DP_BASE_DIR

Comment: so the constant is defined in the class file you are trying to load using that constant?

Comment: @MacroMan How am i supposed to help otherwise? Don't be simple...

Comment: You need to define the `DP_BASE_DIR` constant before attempting to use it in the `require_once(...)` call. Is error reporting turned on? Usually you would expect to see an error message about undefined constants if error reporting is on ( with appropriate error level set )

Comment: @McLaren what does `var_dump(DP_BASE_DIR);exit;` output if run just before the require? Actually, give outputs for that and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` within your question.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity var_dump(DP_BASE_DIR) outputs string(52) "/home/lonklycom/domains/lonkly.com/public_html/John"

Comment: @McLaren Alright and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` holds the exact same value?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity yes it is. So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: try: `define('DP_BASE_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );` before you call the `require_once` statement

Comment: @McLaren I have tested the info you have given but its not doing the same thing for me. It includes the required file. Odd...

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] === DP_BASE_DIR);` is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if this makes sense to you, I have tested this out using:

test.php

```
<?php
  define('DP_BASE_DIR', '/var/www/devspace');
  if (!(defined('DP_BASE_DIR'))) { die('This file should not be called directly.'); }
  require DP_BASE_DIR."/test2.php";
  var_dump($string);exit;
  // outputs string(4) "test" 
?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php      
  $string = 'test';
?>
```

Isn't that exactly what you're doing? I feel that something else is coming into play here and being left out of the info that has been provided.

The only real issue that I could spot here is that maybe `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` did not hold the exact same value as your `DP_BASE_DIR` but as you have confirmed these to be the same I am scratching my head about other possibilities as this should just work.

EDIT:

do this right before the require:

```
$test = DP_BASE_DIR."/classes/query.class.php";
var_dump($test);exit;
```

Post the result?

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning**:  require_once(DP_BASE_DIR/classes/query.class.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file  or directory in

Seems DP_BASE_DIR constant does not exists. If constant does not exists will use the name of constant, and you get a notice.

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
echo Constant; // outputs "Constant" and issues a notice.
```

Comment: That's the thing though, It was said that they called `var_dump(DP_BASE_DIR);exit;` right before the `require` to get: `string(52) "/home/lonklycom/domains/lonkly.com/public_html/John"`. It clearly exists?

Comment: @IndigoIdentity It is really strange based on the error message. `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] === DP_BASE_DIR);` is it true?

Comment: OP is @McLaren, they have not yet provided this info. Nice debugging though :)

Comment: FYI, this is the error that comes about from not being careful with character cases when calling constants: `Notice: Use of undefined constant Dp_base_dir - assumed 'Dp_base_dir'`

Comment: Yes, it comes with error if error_reporting is enabled. But if `DP_BASE_DIR` contains like "asd" the error message should be `require_once(asd/classes/query.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`